# Python Transfer a tensor feed_dict output into a list

Tags: python, tensorflow

When I run an operation with a session using tensorflow,the result is a tensor with exact calculation results.How can I transfer it into an iterable list,in other words,use this tensor to do other works? I am new to tf, I hope someone can help me.

```
 print sess.run(y, feed_dict={x: feed_x, dropout_keep_prob: dropout_prob})
```

Comment: What have you done to solve the problem? any code snippets?

Comment: I used list() to transfer a tensor,but failed

Comment: you may need to post your code, what are you doing? and then someone can help if something is wrong in that?

Comment: print sess.run(y, feed_dict={x: feed_x, dropout_keep_prob: dropout_prob})

Comment: Here is the code,no errors.I want to obtain the result in  tensor "y"

Comment: I think sess.run will return numpy array. So you are printing the array as output. Please go through this link for more info https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/15056/how-to-use-lists-in-tensorflow

Answer (score 0):

It should be already iterable, as the output is a numpy array.
The following code should work, if y is a one dimensional array.

```
result = sess.run(y, feed_dict={x: feed_x, dropout_keep_prob: dropout_prob})
result_list = list(result)
```

Could you give us the definition of y in the graph? In this case we could be more useful to you.